# How can I add line feed after itemize?

Tags: spacing, lists, line-breaking

How can I add line feed after `itemize`? Some vertical spacing would be even better, I think.
My document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label=--}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt}
\begin{document}
List of items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item one,
\item Item two,
\item Item three
\end{itemize}
That was the list of items.
\end{document}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label=--}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt}
\begin{document}
List of items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item one,
\item Item two,
\item Item three
\end{itemize}~\\
That was the list of items.
\end{document}
```

Space generated by `~\\` is a little to big for me.
What do I need to change in preamble to get effect like this? Is vertical spacing in this case better than line feed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With package `enumitem`, you could use the parameter `after`, such as

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt,after=\newline}
```

or use `\vspace` there with a value you like, such as

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt,after=\vspace{.5\baselineskip}}
```

Comment: This might work, but I still think vertical spacing would be better, because full line-feed does not look good for me.

Comment: `.5\baselineskip` means half of normal line feed, right?

Comment: I've changed `px` into `pt` as XeTeX doesn't understand the former.

Comment: A little problem showed up. That is nod big one but... If a list finishes the section, I got extra vspacing in addition to what's already there. Can it be avoided? Half line-feed is almost unnoticeable compared to vspace I currently got after ending section, but still...

Comment: @Ichibann In cases where lists end a section, you could use `\begin{itemize}[after=\relax]` there.

Comment: It works like a charm for a single itemize, but when you have an itemize **inside** an itemize, I have an error: `there's no line to end here`. However the layout is still good for me. Is there any workaround to solve the error?